Highcharts link between nodes on right
in this sample, the lines E-G and C-G are separated.
Is there a way to link these lines into a single G node ?

The graph was built using highcharts library in a treegraph type.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" class="win chrome chrome60 webkit webkit5">
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treegraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<figure class="highcharts-figure"><div id="container"></div></figure>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [
        {
            type: 'treegraph',
            keys: ['parent', 'id', 'level'],
            data: [
                ['', 'A'],
                ['', 'D'],
                ['A', 'B'],
                ['A', 'C'],
                ['D', 'E'],
                ['D', 'F'],
                ['E', 'G'],
                ['C', 'G'],
                ['G', 'H'],
                ['G', 'I'],
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                pointFormat: '{point.id}',
            },
        }
    ]
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>

I tried others chart configurations, without success.

Unfortunately, in Highcharts, the treegraph series type represents hierarchical data in which each node has exactly one parent. So it's sadly not possible to have one G node with two parents C and F.
